# How do I fit a huge image in a screen automatically using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

My home.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <img class="mod" src="image.jpg" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Note:
1. I haven't put  within a  as I am not aware if it a good practice, but I have noticed it in all wesites.
2. Didn't use width and height properties in  tag, because I was not sure how it would help me.

Now the image is very huge and I want to automatically fit it any of the screens of desktop, ipads or mobile in the below way:

1. horizontally, the image should occupy the full screen
2. vertically, the image should occupy half the screen

It is okay if the part of the image is cropped while scaling vertically.

I know the  allows viewport, but I want to do it in CSS3. This is what I did:

```
img.mod { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; background-size:100% }
```

But it didn't work.

I want my webpage to look this way:

```
Image
Text
Image
Text
.
.
.
```

The images should fit completely the width without scrolling needed.

Comment: are you looking for this result http://jsfiddle.net/a4Z8D/2/ ??

Comment: No, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background size is CSS3 attribute but it works only with background images. In your case you should do something as shown below:

```
body, html{ height:100%;}
img.mod { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; width:100%; height:50%; }
```

If you want this to implement using background then use below code:

```
body, html{ height:100%;}
body { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; background:url(**yourimage**.png) top left no-repeat; background-size: 100% 50%; }
```

Cheers,

Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
background-size:100%
```

to

```
width:100%
```

This will fit the image horizontally across the screen. Note that the height is going to automatically adjust itself to stay in proportion to the width. Trying to set the height to 50% is going to result in a distorted image, because chances are 100% body X 50% body are not the natural dimensions of the image.

To crop the image at 50%, there are a few options. You can google around to find others, but a method I have used before is wrapping the image in a container with a style like this:

```
.container {
    height:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVpPA/1/)